# Issue with nested forms and posting simultaneously to two associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

So I have tried now to do this for multiple hours pulling from different sources. I'm sure I can probably hack this together in a very ugly way with multiple creates, but im sure there is a simple way to do this.

im trying to create a simple time and task tracker.  I have a time tracker table that records the start and end times of a task and the task id.

There is an associated table that contains the title and details of the task.

When I try to .save! it

it abandons the save  with ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Task must exist):

the logic seems to be that it should first try to create the task details (title and details) which creates the ID, and then it should create the timerecord(timetracker) record and include the task id in the task_id column of the time record.  But based on the error, guess this is not happening.

I appreciate any help getting this working or point me in the right direction of what im doing incorrectly.

##########
**Edit** After posting, I realized that a task can have multiple time records, since a user can stop and restart on the same task that creates a new record with the same task ID. I've changed the task model from has_one to has_many.
###########

Here are the two models

```
class Timerecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  #has_one :timerecord #this has been changed to
  has_many :timerecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :timerecord   
end
```

in my Timetracker controller #new & #create & private

```
def new
  @timetracker = Timerecord.new
  @timetracker.build_task
end

  def create
    @timetracker = Timerecord.new(timetracker_params)
      if @timetracker.save
        flash[:notice] = "Time Tracker Started"
        redirect_to timetracker_index_path
      end
  end

private #at the tail of permit you will see including the task attribute title
def timetracker_params
      params.require(:timerecord).permit(:user_id, :agency_id, :client_id, :task_id, :is_billable, :time_start, :time_end, :manual_input_hours, :timerecordgroup_id, :is_paused, :service_type_id, task_attributes: [:title])
  end
```

and the form

```
<%= form_with(model: @timetracker, url: timetracker_index_path, local: true) do |f| %>
  ... a bunch of fields for @timetracker
    
    <%#= fields_for :task, @timetracker.task do |t| %>
    <%#= t.text_field :title, class: "form-control shadow-sm", placeholder: "Title" %>
    <%# end %>

 ... more fields for timetracker 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Quick suggestions:

1. Could you check what is the body of the HTTP request that is being made on form submit?
2. Try using `has_many :timerecord, inverse_of: :task` not sure that's the case here though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to know which model is nested within the other and which one you're going to call the `save` method on.

Since your models are:

```
class Timerecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  #has_one :timerecord #this has been changed to
  has_many :timerecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :timerecord   
end
```

You should call `save` on the `Task` model (which will also save `timerecord`) and not on the `TimeRecord` model because your `Task` model is the one accepting the nested attributes for `TimeRecord` model and not the other way around.

Your controller should look something like this:

```
def create
    @timetracker = Task.new(task_params)
      if @timetracker.save
        flash[:notice] = "Time Tracker Started"
        redirect_to timetracker_index_path
      end
  end

private 
def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(#your permitted params for task, timetracker_attributes: [:title])
  end
```

if you notice, your `Task` model accepts nested attributes for `timetracker`, hence you should permit `timetracker_attributes` and not `task_attributes`.
It's easy to know which nested params you should permit, just look at your models and see which model the `accept_nested_attributes_for` is refering to and then just add _attributes at the end.

Check out the `accept_nested_attributes_for` documentation, it should help
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to comment and provide feedback. Got this working. This was a good reference as well with a step by step if anyone comes across this in the future https://meaganwaller.com/use-a-nested-dynamic-form-with-a-hasmany-through-association-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as such, just a few suggestions to point you in the right direction as there are quite a few things wrong with your implementation.

1. you don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :timerecord`
   in task, as you aren't creating timerecords at the time you are creating/editing the task.
2. you don't need to require the nested attributes for task in the TimerecordController
3. the form should have a hidden_field for the :task_id - this is primarily why you are getting the error.
4. but you don't have an associated task for the timerecord so in addition you need to assign it at the point you generate a new timerecord. Your TimerecordController new action should be something like:

```
def new
  @timetracker = Timerecord.new
  @timetracker.task_id = params[:task_id]
end
```

5. which means you also need to ensure you are sending task_id to the new action, for example `new_timerecord_path(task_id: my_task_instance.id)`